# How to detect dates and convert to datetime64 data type

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am reading data from a csv with `pandas.read_csv`. One of the columns has date information in different formats (no standard ISO 8601 or the like). I want to make sure that Pandas can detect the date format without requiring further input from the user. To be honest I am not really sure how to start. I know that Pandas can `infer_datetime_format` however it does not catch all data variations or might throw an error.

My datasets have several million rows so the process can be pretty time consuming. My idea was to load only the first 100 rows (`nrows=100`) and then let the function detect the date format. From the datasets I have seen so far it could be dd-mm-yy, dd-mm-yyyy, yyyy-mm-dd (and different variations with ,.- seperators), Jan 19, January 2019, 1 January 2019, etc. Also I have text in English (December) and German (Dezember).

I thought about running something like a for loop for every item in the column, prepare cases with different formats, maybe in a `try` `except` block and let Pyton detect the correct format for the first 100 entries. (build different cases with date formats from: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Does that approach even make sense? Or how would you go about? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pd.to_datetime` can be over an order of magnitude slower when you let it try to infer the format. With mixed formats, you can try to parse it several times:

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce
                           # dd-mm-yy    dd-mm-YYYY    YYYY-mm-dd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['12-01-01', '12-01-2001', '2001-07-05',
                            'Jan 19', 'January 2019', '1 January 2019']})
```

#### Code:

```
formats = ['%d-%m-%y', '%d-%m-%Y', '%Y-%m-%d', '%b %y', '%B %Y', '%d %B %Y']
reduce(lambda l,r: l.combine_first(r), 
       [pd.to_datetime(df.date, format=fmt, errors='coerce') for fmt in formats])

0   2001-01-12
1   2001-01-12
2   2001-07-05
3   2019-01-01
4   2019-01-01
5   2019-01-01
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

In general `pd.to_datetime` can flexibly parse most of those formats if you specify `dayfirst`. Though this will still be slower than trying to parse it several times with the specified formats.

```
pd.to_datetime(df.date, errors='coerce', dayfirst=True)
#0   2001-01-12
#1   2001-01-12
#2   2001-07-05
#3          NaT
#4   2019-01-01
#5   2019-01-01
#Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]

df = pd.concat([df]*10000, ignore_index=True)
%timeit reduce(lambda l,r: l.combine_first(r), [pd.to_datetime(df.date, format=fmt, errors='coerce') for fmt in formats])
#287 ms ± 2.35 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit pd.to_datetime(df.date, errors='coerce', dayfirst=True)
#5.79 s ± 36.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

So you still win immensely even trying to parse it several times, plus you don't miss some of the non-standard formats.

Comment: Great, that was exactly what I was looking for. And thank you for the thorough explanation. Really helpful! I very much like the first option with parsing several times with specified formats. If a format cannot be detected it will be stored as `NaT` correct? Do you know of any more tweaks with regards to performance (I am looking at around 10 million rows...)?

Comment: @pythoneer yes `NaT` is the datetime64 null value. As for the performance, I'm not sure of any other simple tweaks. This will certainly be faster than looping over the rows, but date parsing does tend to be on the slower side.

Answer (score 0):

You might try [dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which supports parsing dates in multiple languages.

From their documentation:

```
>>> # parsing ambiguous date
>>> parse('02-03-2016')  # assumes english language, uses MDY date order
datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 2, 0, 0)
>>> parse('le 02-03-2016')  # detects french, uses DMY date order
datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 2, 0, 0)
```